# Isotope height of elements not set correctly

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, jquery-isotope

So the height of my Isotope elements isn't set correctly, the elements overlap each other:
http://bz-fotografie.de/kundengalerie/gallery-1/

Strange thing is, it works on my localhost, but not live.

I'm not a JS guru, so the structure in my helper.js might not be the best...

Answer (score 1):

It seems to work now. I used the imagesloaded.js and added this after my isotope call:

```
$container.imagesLoaded().progress( function() {
    $container.isotope('layout');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you run .isotope the images are not yet loaded, so the plugin cannot calculate their size..

You have some different options to choose from

1. Start isotope after the images have loaded.. $(window).load(function(){/*init plugin here*/})
2. Use the imagesLoaded plugin: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/help.html#imagesloaded_plugin

3.call reLayout once the images are loaded $(window).load(function(){$('#thumbs').isotope('reLayout');});

4.if the li elements are fixed size, then give them dimensions through CSS, and isotope will pick them up..

Credits: Stack overflow..

Comment: Thanks solai, but option 1 is what I had tried first, to no avail... 

I tried option 2 and 3 now, but I can't figure out how to get it to work. Probably something wrong with the nesting of the functions in helper.js (which must look horrible to the savvy)...